# How to format number values for ggplot2 legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on finishing up a graph generated using ggplot2 like so...

```
ggplot(timeSeries, aes(x=Date, y=Unique.Visitors, colour=Revenue)) 
+ geom_point() + stat_smooth() + scale_y_continuous(formatter=comma)
```

I have attached the result and you can see the numeric values in the legend for Revenue do not have a comma. How can I add a comma to those values? I was able to use scale_y_continuous for the axis, can that be used for the legend also?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Note 2014-07-16: the syntax in this answer has been obsolete for some time. Use [metasequoia's answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15007117/143319)**

---

Yep - just a matter of getting the right scale_colour_ layer figured out.  Try:

```
ggplot(timeSeries, aes(x = Date, y = Unique.Visitors, colour = Revenue)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth() +
    scale_y_continuous(formatter = comma) +
    scale_colour_continuous(formatter = comma)
```

I personally would also move my the colour mapping to the geom_point layer, so that it doesn't give you that odd line behind the dot in the legend:

```
ggplot(timeSeries, aes(x = Date, y = Unique.Visitors)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = Revenue)) +
    stat_smooth() +
    scale_y_continuous(formatter = comma) +
    scale_colour_continuous(formatter = comma)
```

Answer (score 62):

Just to keep current, in ggplot2_0.9.3 the working syntax is:

```
require(scales)
ggplot(timeSeries, aes(x=Date, y=Unique.Visitors, colour=Revenue)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels=comma) +
    scale_colour_continuous(labels=comma)
```

Also see [this exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987308/number-formatting-axis-labels-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Use ``scale_size_continuous(labels = comma)`` if you have set ``size`` (rather than ``colour``) inside the ``aes()``, and likewise with shape and fill I guess.

Answer (score 8):

...as I stumbled over this older thread, maybe it makes sense to add you need to load `library("scales")`, otherwise you get the following error message

`Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : object 'comma' not found`

Comment: Needed to re-install the "scales" package and load it manually to get this solution to work

Comment: You may overcome this by using `scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::comma)`

Answer (score 1):

Note that `comma` and `comma_format()` have been superceded by `label_comma()`. Here's what I typically use:

```
... + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_comma()) +
scale_colour_continuous(labels = scales::label_comma())
```