# Number formatting axis labels in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a fairly simple chart using ggplot2 0.9.1.

```
x <- rnorm(100, mean=100, sd = 1) * 1000000
y <- rnorm(100, mean=100, sd = 1) * 1000000
df <- data.frame(x,y)

p.new <- ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point()
print(p.new)
```

Which works, but ggplot2 defaults to scientific notation that is inappropriate for my audience. If I want to change the x-axis label format by entering:

```
p.new + scale_x_continuous(labels = comma)
```

I get:

> Error in structure(list(call = match.call(), aesthetics = aesthetics,  :
> object 'comma' not found

What am I doing wrong? I note that the language changed recently from "formatter" to "labels". Perhaps I'm misreading the man page?

**Edit: I was indeed misreading the man page**

Need to load `library(scales)` before attempting this.

Comment: Good thought, but that seems to create a 1 item list that creates problems of its own:`Error in scale_labels.continuous(scale, major) : 
      Breaks and labels are different lengths`

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @RomanLuštrik - just thought of that (also hoped that I might fix the problem simply by approaching from another angle... no such luck.)

Comment: Solved: need to load `library(scales)` before trying this. Slapping head.

Comment: You can post this as an answer and check it as the correct answer. You may need to wait some time before you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

One needs to load `library(scales)` before attempting this.

Answer (score 6):

More generally, you can control some nice parameters using the "scales" package. One of its functions is number_format().

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()
```

For formatting your numbers, you can use the function number_format(). It offers some nice possibilities, such as controlling the number of decimals (here 2 decimals) and your decimal mark (here ',' instead of '.')

```
p + scale_y_continuous(
  labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.01,
                                 decimal.mark = ','))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to add commas and decimals to ggplot using [`scales::comma_format()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/versions/0.4.1/topics/comma_format).

Essentially allowing for a prettyNum() style of formatting.

```
Seatbelts_df <- as.data.frame(Seatbelts)

ggplot(data=Seatbelts_df, aes(x=Seatbelts_df$drivers, y=Seatbelts_df$DriversKilled, color=factor(Seatbelts_df$law))) +
  geom_jitter(alpha=0.5) +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold")) +
  labs(title="Amount of Drivers on Road vs Amount of deaths", subtitle = "Dataset from package datasets::Seatbelts", x ="Drivers on Road", y="Amount of Deaths", color="Seatbelt Law?") +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Yes", "No"), values = c("blue", "red")) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(Seatbelts_df$drivers)), color="black", linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  scale_x_continuous(
  labels = scales::comma_format(big.mark = ',',
                                 decimal.mark = '.'))
```

[image: example of output with commas]