# Force R to stop plotting abbreviated axis labels (scientific notation) - e.g. 1e+00

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, axes

In ggplot2 how can I stop axis labels being abbreviated - e.g. `1e+00, 1e+01` along the x axis once plotted? Ideally, I want to force R to display the actual values which in this case would be `1,10`.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1, 1e9, length.out=100), y=sample(100))
# displays x-axis in scientific notation
p  <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
p

# displays as you require
library(scales)
p + scale_x_continuous(labels = label_comma())
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Out of interest, what other 'label' options are there for axes in ggplot2 with the scales package?

Comment: Please visit also [this ggplot2.org page](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html), it was very helpful for me with a similar issue.

Comment: That link is outdated. Now you want to have a look at https://ggplot2-book.org/scale-position.html#label-functions - `scales::comma` is a shorthand for `scales::label_comma`, etc.

Comment: hmm; just trying this, I'm getting a new error: `Error: Breaks and labels are different lengths`

Comment: This didn't work for me until I saw [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11995652/11736959) ...which basically said that you needed to run first `library(scales)`

Comment: It always seems to error for me until I use `labels = scales::comma` instead of just `labels = comma`. I guess I have some masking going on but I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: If I use dual y-axis, this solution seems will not work out.

Comment: I found that the scales::comma solution worked but removed my log10 scaling in the process

Answer (score 95):

Did you try something like :

```
options(scipen=10000)
```

before plotting ?

Comment: This works by setting a higher *penalty* for deciding to use scientific notation. More explanation in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18600721/1080804

Answer (score 64):

Just an update to what @Arun made, since I tried it today and it didn't work because it was actualized to

```
+ scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::comma)
```

Comment: @Arun's answer should work fine as-is, perhaps you neglected to include the `require(scales)`? This imports the package that contains the `comma` scale. As you've discovered, you can also specify the package when referring to it instead of requiring it beforehand.

Answer (score 26):

As a more general solution, you can use `scales::format_format` to remove the scientific notation. This also gives you lots of control around how exactly you want your labels to be displayed, as opposed to `scales::comma` which only does comma separations of the orders of magnitude.

For example:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(1, 1e9, length.out=100), y=sample(100))

# Here we define spaces as the big separator
point <- format_format(big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE)

# Plot it
p  <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
p + scale_x_continuous(labels = point)
```

Comment: format_format is currently retried from package scales. you should either use label_number() or label_date() instead.

Answer (score 23):

There is a solution that don't require scales library.

You can try:

```
# To deactivate scientific notation on y-axis:

    p + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))

# To activate scientific notation on y-axis:

    p + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = TRUE))

# To deactivate scientific notation on x-axis:

    p + scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))

# To activate scientific notation on x-axis:

    p + scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 10):

Extending the original question to comprise fractions as well, i.e. 1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001 etc. and avoiding trailing zeros

```
p + scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) sprintf("%g", x))
```

Comment: This is much nicer from an aesthetic perspective!

Comment: This also worked without upsetting log10 scale and agree it has more aesthetic appearl

Answer (score 5):

If you additionally want to have commas as a thousand separator, you can use the following:

```
p + scale_x_continuous(labels=function(x) format(x, big.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE))
```

Comment: This worked without upsetting my log10 scale

Answer (score 2):

```
p + scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 1))
```

the `accuracy = 1` is for whole numbers, you could also use `accuracy = 0.1` if you wanted one decimal place, `accuracy = 0.01` for two decimal places, etc.

[similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59658913/12836787)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the simplest general solution to set the penalty that R uses for scientific notation higher?

i.e set `scipen()` to a number that you are comfortable with.

e.g. If your axis maximum on charts is likely to be 100 000, setting `scipen(200000)` will ensure that R (and ggplot) will use standard notation for all numbers below 200000 and there will be no requirement to add any lines to the ggplot function.

Comment: same as this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14564026/7941188

Answer (score -1):

```
library(scales)

ggplot(data, aes(salary)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = comma)
```

here `scale_x_continuous(labels = comma)` can solve that issue.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.