# Forcing a 1e3 instead of 1000 format in ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having some trouble with the y formatting ranges.  When I use `scale_y_log10()` in my plot, it decides that having the scale 0.1, 10, 1000 is the way to do it.  I really need it to display it as **1e-1, 1e1, 1e3**.  `math_format` help page is not helpful without the format I need to know.

Anything I can answer I will.

Comment: Does the [first example here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/annotation_logticks.html) help you?

Comment: I was looking for "1e3" type of label instead.  Thank you though.

Comment: related - just the other way round: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563989/force-r-to-stop-plotting-abbreviated-axis-labels-e-g-1e00-in-ggplot2/14564026#14564026

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `breaks` and `labels` parameters of `scale_y_log10` as in

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=subset(movies, votes > 1000)) +
  aes(x = rating, y = votes / 10000) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(0.1, 1, 10), labels = expression(10^-1, 10^0, 10^1)) +
  geom_point()
```

This might not be an elegant solution, but it works if you only have a limited number of plots.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that R uses an not well-understood penalty mechanism for deciding whether to print in normal or scientific notation. This is decided by `options( scipen )`.

The value represents the penalty R applies to the number of characters it would take to print in scientific notation vs. fixed point, so `options(scipen = 3)` would mean that `R` adds 3 to the number of characters it takes to print say `1e2` and compares it to the number of characters it needs to print the fixed point equivalent and prints the number with the lower number of characters (so in this case `1e2` = 3 characters, + 3 penalty = 6, whereas `100` equals 3 characters so `100` gets printed. To fix you example just set `options(scipen = -10)` to always favour printing scientific notation over fixed point. So (using @PeterB's example) you can use `scipen` which should allow you to not worry about manual break setting...

```
options(scipen = -10)
ggplot(data=subset(movies, votes > 1000)) +
  aes(x = rating, y = votes / 10000) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to achieve what you ask, with automatic limits and breaks, and without side-effects is this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
library(scales)
ggplot(data=subset(movies, votes > 1000)) +
  aes(x = rating, y = votes / 10000) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x, n=3), 
                labels = trans_format("log10")) +
  geom_point()
```

I rather prefer to use superscripts for the powers of ten, and hide the minor grid,
and add ticks spaced according to logs. This is also rather easy to achieve:

```
ggplot(data=subset(movies, votes > 1000)) +
  aes(x = rating, y = votes / 10000) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x, n=3), 
               labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  annotation_logticks(sides="l") + 
  geom_point()
```

The code above is adapted from the examples in the annotation_logticks help, [annotation_logticks](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotation_logticks.html?q=logticks). There is a lot of flexibilty for adjusting the exact format.

Comment: I'll upvote this (I want to because I didn't know about this before) if you go to the effort of giving an example of this in action (you can copy paste from the link you gave if you really want!). Otherwise this is really just a comment and should be left as such.

Comment: The link to annotation_logticks is dead - probably now https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotation_logticks.html