# How can I keep the linear values when I plot in log scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using this code to plot both axes in log scale:

```
ggplot(all, aes(x=area, y=rl))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_log10()+
  scale_y_log10()+
  theme_bw()
```

And I get a figure like this:

[image]

But I would like to keep the axes in the original values instead of log values. Something like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

```
 all <- structure(list(rl = c(92497.5, 263421, 263421, 185338, 83769.6,185338, 185338, 90769.6, 90769.6, 90769.6), area = c(1310.534,10385.8523, 10385.8523, 7163.9071, 1610.9726, 7163.9071, 7163.9071,1610.9726, 1610.9726, 1610.9726)), .Names = c("rl", "area"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("100142","100143", "100144", "100145", "100146", "100147", "100148", "102055","102056", "102057"))
```

Comment: You mean you don't want a scientific notation of axis labels? Then try e.g. `scale_y_log10(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE))`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563989/force-r-to-stop-plotting-abbreviated-axis-labels-e-g-1e00-in-ggplot2, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563989/force-r-to-stop-plotting-abbreviated-axis-labels-e-g-1e00-in-ggplot2

Comment: use `library("scales"); ... scale_y_log10(label=comma)`