# How to change the scale of y-axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'm trying to scale the y-axis from 0 to 100000 in order to get 10000 between each point in the scale but I got this result. what's the proper way to scale the axis by 10000? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8M0c.jpg)

Comment: have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563989/force-r-to-stop-plotting-abbreviated-axis-labels-e-g-1e00-in-ggplot2

Comment: Thank you so much. This code works well!