# How can I make the values in the graph real numbers not complex, in R?

Tags: r, plot

I have a graph and the y-axis values in the graph are always in complex numbers although that's not the case in the list i have. How can I make them real numbers? basically I want the values in the y-axis in the graph on the right to look like the one in the left [image]

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563989/force-r-to-stop-plotting-abbreviated-axis-labels-e-g-1e00-in-ggplot2

Comment: `options(scipen = 99999)` should work

Comment: It would help us answer if you provided some sample data and the code that you used to produce the graph.