# ggplot2 y-axis not showing numeric number after summarised

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was following the instruction of google data analytics online course for this Case study of the Cyclistic bikesharing company.
The last step after I use this code visualize the number of rides by rider type, the plot doesn't show the numeric number on y-axis.

```
all_trips_cleaned %>%
mutate(weekday = wday(started_at, label = TRUE)) %>% 
group_by(member_casual, weekday) %>% 
summarise(number_of_rides = n(),average_duration = mean(ride_length)) %>% 
arrange(member_casual, weekday) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = weekday, y = number_of_rides, fill = member_casual)) + geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

This is what i get currently

[image]

How can I change the y-axis label as numbers?

Comment: To remove scientific notation, try to call `options(scipen = 999)` before your call to the data transformation %>% ggplot

Comment: Alternately `... + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(big.mark = ","))` (with lots of other options available in `?scales::label_number`)

Comment: [Force R to stop plotting abbreviated axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563989/force-r-to-stop-plotting-abbreviated-axis-labels-scientific-notation-e-g-1e)